# Angular how to show live value of json object

Tags: node.js, angular

In angular , I am trying to display one json object to client html. Using below route on server side.

```
const express = require('express');
const jsonRoute = express.Router();

jsonRoute .route('/json').get(function (req, res) {
    var JsonObj = { rank: 73 } ;
  res.end(JSON.stringify(JsonObj));
});

setInterval(function(){ 
    JsonObj.rank = parseInt(Math.random()*100);
}, 1000); // this interval may be anything.from ms to minutes.

module.exports = jsonRoute ;
```

this works on http://localhost:4000/json and displays ,

```
{"rank":73}
```

But does not show the values changed in setInterval. And same route i am using in a angular service (using http).

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class getjsonService {
  uri = "http://localhost:4000/json";
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  jsondata(){
    return this.http.get(`${this.uri}`);    
  }
}
```

This value i am displaying in component html page. The problem is, it is not showing updated value of json. Please suggest how can i show live json value in angular. Please note, in realtime my json object going to be big in size , around 100 keys and value and i want to show live value for all key. And also change value interval may not be fix as one second. it may be in milliseconds as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

By default http will not persistent the connection. It's http protocol limitation not from angular.If you want to show the value in real time, you need to use web sockets.

There are lot of library out there will help with real time data connection. https://socket.io/ is very popular. check this out

Tutorial :https://alligator.io/angular/socket-io/

Comment: Thanks @Ravin. This socket.io looks promising. I will go through the suggested urls and try to implement in my solution.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is a structural one with how RESTful architecture works. Your server only sends the new data to your angluar app when your *app* asks for it, not when your *server* detects a change. What you will need to do is either add a set timeout in your angular project that will call the server for the new data every few seconds.

```
setInterval(function(){ var JsonData = getJsonService.jsondata() }, 3000);
console.log(JsonData);
//This will refetch the data every 3 seconds you can lower this number to make it refresh more often
```

The other option is to rewrite your server to use web-sockets as Ravin pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

In your node.js code, you are re-inializing the `JsonObj` variable every time the request is made.  You should store the value as a global variable:

```
const express = require('express');
const jsonRoute = express.Router();

var JsonObj = { rank: 73 };

jsonRoute .route('/json').get(function (req, res) {
    res.json(JsonObj);
});

setInterval(function(){ 
    JsonObj.rank = parseInt(Math.random()*100);
}, 1000); // this interval may be anything.from ms to minutes.

module.exports = jsonRoute ;
```